# Spring MVC - one-to-many how to get a foreign key ID in the controller

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a very basic one-to-many relation: Post has many Comments. I'd like to create/update a comment from the Post page (à la Rails RESTful) url like: posts/3/comments/2/edit (to update a comment for example. So here is what I have in the PostsController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/posts/{post_id}/comments")
public class CommentsController {

 @Autowired
    private CommentService commentService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initUpdateForm(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        Comment comment = commentService.findById(id);
        return "comments/form";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/edit", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String processUpdateForm(@Valid Comment comment, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
                                    SessionStatus status) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "comments/form";
        } else {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Comment updated successfully !");
            commentService.save(comment);
            status.setComplete();

            return "redirect:/posts/{post_id}";

        }
    }

}
```

In the processUpdateForm the value of post_di is NULL. How can I get the required post_id ?
Thnx

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is to find the corresponding Post by the post_id supplied in the url:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/edit", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public String processUpdateForm(@PathVariable Long post_id, @Valid Comment comment, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
                                    SessionStatus status) {
        Post post = postService.findById(post_id);
        comment.setPost(post);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "comments/form";
        } else {
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Comment updated successfully !");
            commentService.save(comment);
            status.setComplete();

            return "redirect:/posts/{post_id}";
        }
    }
```

May be there is a better solution, I'd be grateful it to be shared here.